# cross module view file loading codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, module, hmvc

I have two modules in codeigniter hmvc.

1- Acess
2- Display

Here is My Access Module Controller

```
class Access extends MX_Controller
{

    public function __contstruct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->module('display');
    }
    public function index()
    {

        echo modules::run('display/login');
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        //$this->load->view('login');
        echo modules::run('display/test');
    }
}
```

and here is my display module controlelr

```
class Display extends MX_Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('login'); // This file resides in Access module view folder
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

So, When acess controller comes in contact, technically it should access display module login function in controller which in return should display the login form along with the header and footer.

Here the problem is that the login.php is placed in access module view file which is being accessed from display module controller. So, I guess the question is pretty much clear for every one.

Comment: I did find a tricky solution to this hmvc thing such as I created as many folders as many modules I am using in my website. In this way, my display module can display all views of other modules.So, FIXED. Actually the problem was that i wanted my modules have separate view files in their own folder hierarchy which my display module could not show upon call. So, Tried the way around.

Answer (score 0):

When loading the view you just need to add the module name before the view name and it will work. So $this->load->view('login'); will become $this->load->view('access/login');

That should work.